# Google Datastudio: Categorize new and returning user id based on their first appearance date

Tags: looker-studio

I want to categorise users to the new and returning users based on their first appearance date in Data Studio, so if I select the date range of  June 1, 2019, to June 30, 2019, every user with first appearance date is on that period is categorised as a new and every users before that period categorised as the returning users.

[The data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Geu.png):

| user_id | Firstcontact |
| --- | --- |
| 9020784665 | 21/05/19 |
| 80302116604 | 21/05/19 |
| 34032004987 | 02/06/19 |
| 85963021828 | 03/06/19 |
| 42703694037 | 04/06/19 |
| 7985228940 | 05/06/19 |
| 39174203617 | 06/06/19 |
| 62014629759 | 06/06/19 |
| 71599733666 | 06/06/19 |
| 3617458365 | 06/06/19 |

I was considering to use the `CASE` function but nothing seemed to work.

I expect the output of new users based on selected date in Data Studio

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 1):

This is something you'll need to create a segment for in Google Analytics to use in Data Studio